# How to export a MSSQL table in MSSQL studio express 2005?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, maintenance

is there any way to export a table to a file without any additional tools? I can't install anything on that server.

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to do this. i dont know exactly how you wanted your results but I will throw some options.

If it is a one time thing you can run a query(`select * from YourTable` if you need all the data in the table) using SSMS and then right click on the results and save it as text/csv file. If you want to do this programatically you can use [bcp utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx). You can also use integration services to export data; if you dont have SSIS on the target machine you can build your package inside another machine that do have SSIS and point it to your table as long as you have access to the table in the source.

Comment: He specified Express, which iirc doesn't come with integration services.  But +1 for the other parts.

Answer (score 0):

Would the results to text or results to file function work for you? The option to do this is located in the toolbar above the query window.